# Not all labels on x-axis are showing in sql server 2008 report

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, charts

Here is my problem.  The bar chart report is showing data on x and y axis 
(y axis has 3 fields - min, max, avg values for time frame) and x axis has task type.
For some reason, the chart only shows task types on the x-axis for some apparently interval, 
even though I have no interval set expressly.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

fixed out the issue!  had to set the interval of the axis properties to 1